Proving $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ given that $x^5,20x+\frac{19}{x}\in\mathbb{Q}$
The first question from RMO 2019 asks:

Suppose $x$ is a nonzero real number such that both $x^5$ and $20x +\frac{19}{x}$ are rational numbers. Prove that $x$ is a rational number.

This is the official answer key that includes a solution to this question. However, I've worked out an alternative solution.

My solution
Using the rationality of $20x+\frac{19}{x}$, we can write $20x+\frac{19}{x}=\frac{p}{q}$ for some integers $p,q$ and $q\neq0$
This gives a quadratic equation in $x$ with integer coefficients. Because we know that this equation has real roots, $x$ can be expressed as $a+\sqrt{b}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $b>0$
Now, using the rationality of $x^5=(a+\sqrt{b})^5$, we find that: $$k_0+k_1\sqrt{b}+k_2b+k_3b^{3/2}+k_4b^2+k_5b^{5/2}\in\mathbb{Q},\text{ for }k_n\in\mathbb{Q}$$
Using the rationality of $b$, we can simplify the above statement to $$k_1\sqrt{b}+k_3b^{3/2}+k_5b^{5/2}=m,\text{ for }m\in\mathbb{Q}$$
Thus, $$\begin{align}
k_3b^{3/2}+k_5b^{5/2}&=m-k_1\sqrt{b}\\
\therefore (k_3b^{3/2}+k_5b^{5/2})^2&=(m-k_1\sqrt{b})^2\\
\therefore k_3^2b^3+2k_3k_5b^4+k_5^2b^5&=m^2-2mk_1\sqrt{b}+k_1^2b
\end{align}$$
Therefore, $\sqrt{b}$ is rational, proving that $x=a+\sqrt{b}$ is rational too.

Actually, I have doubt about the accuracy of my proof because I have never seen any similar problem solved in this way previously (the official solution matches better with my conventional learning). Yet, I still can't find any flaw in my proof. I would be very grateful if someone could confirm that this proof is correct.

As correctly observed by @Zoudelong, this proof is erroneous, since we have not shown that $m,k_1\neq0$ before concluding $\sqrt{b}$ to be rational from the last equation. Their answer posted below provides an alternate way to conclude my proof.

It's unclear for me why the rationality of $\sqrt{b}$ can be deduced from the last equation.

Just an additional short cut:
We have:
$$\begin{aligned} &5a^4\sqrt{b}+10a^2b\sqrt{b}+b^2\sqrt{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\\
\Rightarrow &\sqrt{b}(5a^4+10a^2b+b^2)\in \mathbb{Q}
\end{aligned}  $$
Since $b>0$, $5a^4+10a^2b+b^2\neq 0$, we can directly get $\sqrt{b}\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks! (+1) ${}$

@Soham Saha You are welcome. By the way, I think your proof has a flaw in the last equation, because it may reduced to $2mk_1\sqrt{b}=0$ (?)

Yes, you are right. Let’s me see if I can salvage the proof somehow now…

I think your solution (and what Yves suggested) are the best way to complete my proof then, since my conclusion is erroneous. Thanks again.

@SohamSaha I agree, the 'fifth' (odd) power is the key and we do need this. So It may be better to calculate concretely.

I can propose another solution which I think is quite accessible
Since $20x+\frac {19}x=q\ $ then $\ x^2=\frac{qx-19}{20}=ax+b\ $ with $(a,b)$ rationnals.
Consequently by trivial induction any natural power $x^n=a_nx+b_n$ with $a_n,b_n$ rationals.
Therefore provided $a_5\neq 0$ then $x=\frac{x^5-b_5}{a_5}\in\mathbb Q$.
Calculating from $x^5=x(x^2)^2$ we get $a_5=a^4+3a^2b+b^2$
$a_5=0\iff b=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot a^2$ absurd since $a,b$ rationnals.
